# Where is the rescue method?

Tags: ruby

I can't find `rescue` in any of the Ruby objects. I can find `raise` by doing:

```
Kernel.private_instance_methods.grep(/^rai/)
```

But, where is rescue?

Comment: This is like asking where is `if`.

Comment: @matt This might seems trivial but consider 2 lines `var1 = 42 if 42` and `var2 = 4 * 4`. Both `if` and `*` looks like infix method. ps. As fair I remember in Haskell you can write infix methods.

Comment: @DarekNędza I did not say it is wrong to ask where is `if`. I say that the reason you can't find `rescue` (e.g. it is not listed on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/) is the same as the reason why you can't find `if`.

Comment: @matt I misunderstood you. Sorry.

Comment: @DarekNędza The `if` in `var1 = 42 if 42` is not infix operator as you claim. It is `(var1 = 42) if 42`, different structure from `var2 = (4 * 4)`. The reason `var1` is assigned `nil` when the condition after `if` is false is due to a different reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`rescue`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-rescue) is not a method. It is a keyword, hard-wired into Ruby.

Comment: fascinating, so it this new in Ruby 2.0? I think it used to be part of Object in 1.9.

Comment: Nope, it wasn't part of [Object in 1.9](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Object.html).

Comment: @beautifulcoder Maybe confused with StandardError, ArgumentError etc., which are objects?

Comment: @steenslaq, yes the ruby-doc documentation had raise listed and Exception which has other methods so I wondered where the heck the rest of it was.